# Упала функция mail() на локальном сервере

Tags: php, denwer, sendmail

Доброго времени суток! Использую локальный сервер Денвер, подключил sendmail, работало все отлично, как всегда, настроил, использовал для теста ящик на mail.ru, а потом вдруг работать все перестало! В логе ошибок пишет "POP3 is available only with SSL or TLS connection enabled". Лазая по гуглам, я узнал, что это связанно с переходом почти на авторизацию через SSL. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как быть, может, нужно что-то в настройках sendmail.ini поменять?

Comment: Нет почтовика на майле, но, думаю, там есть в настройках отключение SSL.

Comment: Нет, только что шарил по настройка, нет такого.((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тоже такая проблема была. В sendmail.ini закомментил протокол pop3 и оставил только smtp. По нему прекрасно все работает сейчас.

```
smtp_server=smtp.mail.ru

; smtp port (normally 25)

smtp_port=465

; SMTPS (SSL) support
;   auto = use SSL for port 465, otherwise try to use TLS
;   ssl  = alway use SSL
;   tls  = always use TLS
;   none = never try to use SSL

smtp_ssl=ssl

; the default domain for this server will be read from the registry
; this will be appended to email addresses when one isn't provided
; if you want to override the value in the registry, uncomment and modify

;default_domain=mydomain.com

; log smtp errors to error.log (defaults to same directory as sendmail.exe)
; uncomment to enable logging

error_logfile=error.log

; create debug log as debug.log (defaults to same directory as sendmail.exe)
; uncomment to enable debugging

debug_logfile=debug.log

; if your smtp server requires authentication, modify the following two lines

auth_username=----------.ru

auth_password=-----------

; if your smtp server uses pop3 before smtp authentication, modify the 
; following three lines.  do not enable unless it is required.

;pop3_server=pop.mail.ru

;pop3_username=---------@bk.ru

;pop3_password=----------

; force the sender to always be the following email address
; this will only affect the "MAIL FROM" command, it won't modify 
; the "From: " header of the message content

force_sender=----------@bk.ru

; force the sender to always be the following email address
; this will only affect the "RCTP TO" command, it won't modify 
; the "To: " header of the message content

force_recipient=

; sendmail will use your hostname and your default_domain in the ehlo/helo
; smtp greeting.  you can manually set the ehlo/helo name if required

hostname=mail.ru
```

Comment: Спасибо! Это действительно помогло. )